# How to un-mirror object?

Tags: edit-mode

So I currently have my mesh mirrored to where if you edit one part of the object, it will edit that other side exactly the same way. I want to turn this off since I want to edit my left arm and not the right arm. How would I do this? I already tried turning off X-Mirror under Mesh Options but that didn't work.

Here is a picture of my object
[image]

Comment: If you are using a mirror modifier, simply apply it under the modifiers tab

Comment: That solved it, thank you! I had to get hit apply on a mirror modifier and an armature modifier I added.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it! I had to get hit apply on a mirror modifier and an armature modifier I added.